# store rdd which of type array [Int,String] into to text file or location

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have generated `rdd` using map which of type `array [Int,String]`.

when I use `rdd.saveAsTextFile("path")`

```
rdd.SaveAsTextFile
```

> saveAsTextFile is not a member of Array[Int,String]

Comment: .saveAsTextFile is method of RDD... Array doesn't have such method.

Comment: can you provide complete code?